# Excel IF "TEXT" THEN OPERATION

Tags: excel, if-statement, text

I need an **IF** function with the condition that if the value of the cell **A1** is the letter "G", then the value of the cell **B1** (which is in the accounting number format $) will become negative (multiply by -1) but if that cell contains the letter "I", the number will remain positive.

I have the following but it's not working

```
IF(A2="G",B2*-1,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: What should happen if it is neither G nor I, or are those the only options? Also, what does "not working" mean? What does the formula return? Perhaps a sample screenshot would help here.

Comment: "G" and "I" are the only options, the formula is returning the same number I write but never returning the negative when I write "G". I've attached a screenshot. In the first row the result should show -100 but is returning 100

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the result you're getting.  Also, there's no need to multiply by positive `1`.

Comment: Check the number format of those cells.  Make sure they are set to general.

Comment: I agree do not use B2*1 just use B2, otherwise, formula looks good. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the number format of C2?

Comment: I've changed the format to general but it is still showing the positive only, and not negative

Comment: All the numbers have general format now

Comment: Possibly your `"G"` is not really a `"G"`. Maybe there's a space or other non-printing character.  Try deleting the contents of A2 and just typing a `G` from the keyboard there.

Comment: Thank you, Ron. I can't believe that was my mistake lol

Comment: So was there an extra space?  Try using `TRIM(A2)` for your comparison, just in case an extra space shows up.

Comment: Yes there was an space after the "G", thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula (`IF(A6="G",B6*-1,B6)`) is correct, as I have checked and found below your req result:

```
A    B        C                                                                                                 

G/I IMPORT  RESULT                      
G   $100    -$100                       
I   $200     $200                       
G   $200    -$200                       
I   $500     $500
```